# formatting date with php

Tags: php, codeigniter

So just trying to make things simpler here...

I have a controller with a function in codeigniter as follows:

```
public function formatDate($date)
{
    $info = new DateTime($date); 

    return $date = $info->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

And then in a view I am trying to call this function as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->formatDate($user->last_login); ?>
```

I thought by only having to supply a date, I could make something that was simple and re-usable throughout the entire application.

But when I run the code, I receive this error:

```
Call to undefined method CI_Loader::formatDate()
```

Do I need to put the function in a different place. I want to make the function re-usable and only have to provide the date that needs to be formatted and then returned.

The date to format is stored in the database as a `datetime`

Comment: Where am I using that? How do I fix the issue? Your comment doesn't help at all. A waste of my time to read.

Comment: @shankar, I think that is the error he got. You need to create a controller class in the libraries folder and add your date method to it, then in your other controllers you would extend to the class you created in the libraries folder, then you should be able to call the date method across your app

Comment: Thanks @andre3wap. Glad you could take the time to read my question thoroughly and solve the issue. I did make a library for these functions. It worked!

Comment: For this small function is overkill, would use a helper personally. And load the helper automatically then anywhere in code I can use those functions. I usually have a "base_helper.php" file that contains these.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this inside your view?

```
<?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime($user->last_login)); ?>
```

This way you don't have to create a function for a simple task. Also if you want to format certain dates differently you can.

This required an edit. I found this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

> CodeIgniter does not load Helper Files by default, so the first step in using a Helper is to load it. Once loaded, it becomes **globally available in your controller and views**.

I use CI at my job and have never needed to use helpers before. But it looks like this is what you want.

I still feel that just writing code out for formatting dates is best, but to each his own. Either one of these solutions should be what you want.